# ftpclient does not upload my file

Tags: android, upload, ftp-client

hello all i am trying to upload a small file like 4mb or something with apache commons ftpclient it do not upload my file and gives me no error and says upload successfull 
this is my code please help me thanx in advance..
here goes the code..

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();

                FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

                try {  
                        boolean  result = false;
                        FileInputStream fis = null;

                        client.connect(server);
                        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                        client.login(user, pass);
                        client.makeDirectory("/public_html/"+str); ///str is a name of remote folder

                        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                        client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE );
                        client.changeWorkingDirectory(str);
                        String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/index.htm";
                        File f = new File(path1);
                        String testname = f.getName();

                        fis = new 
                                FileInputStream(f);
                        result = client.storeFile(testname, fis);

                        if (result == true){
                            Log.v("upload","upload successfull");
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.v("upload", "upload failed");
                        }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStacktrace();
                 }
            } 
          }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.changeWorkingDirectory(str);
```

is it likely that the `str` directory does not exist, as the dir you are creating is `"/public_html/"+str`.

Comment: str is the name of directory to be created which is taken as input from Edittext

Comment: yes, i appreciate that. I am just saying there is a inconsistency between `client.makeDirectory("/public_html/"+str);` and `client.changeWorkingDirectory(str);`.

Comment: i want to create a dir called str and then change the working dir to str and upload my file that is  index.htm

Comment: you just have to make sure that you create a dir and cd in this directory. probably `client.changeWorkingDirectory("/public_html/" + str);` is enough

Comment: ok i tried but now also it gives me no error and says upload successfull and the file is not uploaded